# How to call a Win32API function from Ruby?

Tags: ruby, windows, winapi

I want to lock a file as MS Office applications do from a Ruby program so that deletions won't be allowed because "the file is opened on another program".

The Ruby standard library does not seem to be able to do that - I just tried `flock()` - so I'm trying to invoke the [LockFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

```
fd = File.open("locked.file", File::RDWR|File::CREAT, 0644)
fd.write "this file to be locked"
import_array = %w(p i i i i i)
wapi = Win32API.new('kernel32', 'LockFileEx', import_array, "i")
wapi.call(fd, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

The wapi.call fails with a TypeError exception "Can't convert File into String".

What should I use as first item in import_array to represent the file handle ?

How do I pack the file descriptor into a String ? Where do I get the file descriptor structure ?

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: It's much easier to open the file for writing, with exclusive share mode, and then not write to it. You can do that with the standard Ruby file handling. Absolutely no need to poke around with Win32API low level stuff. Just use the standard Ruby code to open a file (no idea what this is, don't know Ruby). Ultimately that will map down to a call to the Win32 API function CreateFile. You cannot expect `flock` to work since that is a co-operative mechanism. And don't expect Office to understand Ruby locking files.

Comment: @DavidHeffenan the goal is to mimic MS Office behavior, on a system where it is not available (and nor MS Journal), to write a test. Opening the file in exclusive share mode `File::EXCL` does the trick. Please write an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan missed the 'r' in your name, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ruby file locking mechanism is co-operative and relies on all parties knowing the convention of the Ruby lock file. Microsoft Office will not co-operate.

Instead I suggest that you get the file system to enforce the lock. Simply open the file with an exclusive lock using standard Ruby file handling mechanisms.

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to map the Ruby file descriptor to a C runtime file descriptor.  I'm not familiar enough with Ruby source to know how to do that; it *may* be an identity transform.

Second, you have to map the C runtime descriptor to a Win32 file handle.  For this, you need [_get_osfhandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks2530z6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Third, you need to fix your call to LockFileEx so that you actually pass a valid OVERLAPPED structure; NULL will NOT work.

Comment: 1) yes, or the Ruby file descriptor object should allow accessing it. 2) OK 3) yes, skipped that for now. Thank you